# VideoSurfaceView - render to file

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I'm using [VideoSurfaceView](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/VideoSurfaceView.java?repo=platform--cts) to render filtered video. I'm doing it buy changing the fragment shader according to my needs. Now I would like to save/render the video after the changes to a file of the same format(Ex. mp4 - h264) but couldn't find how to do it.

PS - saving texture as bitmap and the bitmap to a file is easy but I could find how to do it with videos..

Any experts here?

Comment: I'm not getting it? do you want to save the video frames one by one, or the whole video to a new file?

Comment: The whole video to a file, it could be nice if I could have use openGl in the background to process my video with my fragment shader, but openGl cannot play in the background. As I see it now, I need other library that knows to extract video to frames(not FFmpeg dragons)

Comment: I answered your question, hoping that this will help you get further with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already found out and said in the comments, OpenGL can't export multiple frames as a video.

Though if you simply want to filter/process each frame of a video, then you don't need OpenGL at all, and you don't need a Fragment Shader, you can simply loop through all the pixels yourself.

Now let's say that you process your video one frame at a time, and each frame is a `BufferedImage`, *you can of course use whatever you want or get provided with, as long as you have the option to get and set pixels.*

I'm simply supplying you with a way of calculating and applying a filter, you will have to do the decoding and encoding of the video file yourself.

But back to the `BufferedImage`, first we want to get all the pixels in our `BufferedImage`, we do that using the following.

```
BufferedImage bi = ...; // Here you would get a frame from the video

int width = bi.getWidth();
int height = bi.getHeight();

int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

**Be aware** that depending on the type of image and if the image contains transparency, the `DataBuffer` might vary between a `DataBufferInt` to `DataBufferByte`, etc. You can read about the different `DataBuffers` in the Oracle Docs, [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html).

Now simply by looping through the pixels from the image, then we can apply and create any kind of effect and filtering.

Let's say we want to create a [grayscale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) effect also called a [black-and-white](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-and-white) effect, you would then do that by the following.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        final int index = x + y * width;

        final int pixel = pixels[index];

        final int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF;
        final int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        final int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        final int blue = pixel & 0xFF;

        final int gray = (red + green + blue) / 3;

        pixels[index] = alpha << 24 | gray << 16 | gray << 8 | gray;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply save the image again, or do anything else you would like to do. Though you can also use and draw the `BufferedImage`, because the pixel array provided by the `BufferedImage` will of course change the `BufferedImage` as well.

**Important** if you want to perform a blur effect, then after you calculate each pixel store it into another array, because performing a blur effect, requires the surrounding pixels. Therefore it you replace the old once while you calculate all the pixels, some of the pixels will use the calculated values instead of the actual value.

*The above code also works for images as well of course.*

## Extra

If you want to get RGBA values which is stored in a single `int` then you can do the following.

```
int pixel = 0xFFFF8040; // This is a random testing value

int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF; // Would equal 255 using the testing value
int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF; // ... 255 ...
int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF; // ... 128 ...
int blue = pixel & 0xFF; // ... 64 ...
```

Then if you have the RGBA values and want to combine them to a single `int` then you can do the following.

```
int alpha = 255;
int red = 255;
int green = 128;
int blue = 64;

int pixel = alpha << 24 | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;
```

If you only have the RGB values then you just do, either `red << 16 | green  << 8 | blue` or you do `255 << 24 | red << 16 | green  << 8 | blue`

Comment: Hi, I don't think that your methos is the right way to go. First of all - every video is encoded, for Ex. MP4 container with h264, and every video constructed from audio/video/metadata boxes. You can't just take pixels and create an image out of them. You need to decode them with a decoder, usualy a third-party lib like FFmpeg or jCodec.
Secondly - BufferedImage is not part of the Android SDK

Comment: @powerX as I pointed out in the questions, "let's say" it's a `BufferedImage` we get in return/create when we decode the video. You have to do the decoding and encoding yourself (unless you find a library which can perform that), I simply supplied you with the way of calculating and applying filters.

Comment: Can you explain please the line:
BufferedImage bi = ...; // Where here you get it from the video stream
Did you ment to get all the video's bytes and put them in the BufferedImage?

Comment: @powerX Basically there you would get a frame from the video (of course decoding the video, etc) though if you can simply decode the video and get the frame as an array of pixels that would be better, because then you don't have to use a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: it might work for one frame(haven't tried it yet) but how can I do it for all the frames of the video?

Comment: @powerX simply by looping through all the frames!

Comment: Ok but this is my problem, I don't know how you can loop all over frames, if you'll supply a code for it than I'll mark it as an answer. I know to do it with jCodec but its getFrame() is too slow because its decoding each frame in ~1000 millis.

Comment: @powerX well either use jCodec or find another tool, also only decode all the frames once, don't decode them multiple times! After you've decoded them once, save those frames and re-use them each time you need to use them again.

Comment: I'm decoding them just once, but decoding every frame of a video takes 1 second. Consider that if fps is 30 as standard in Android than for a video of 10 seconds: 10 * 30(frames) * 1(sec) = 300 seconds which is 5 minutes processing time!! and only for 10 seconds video. So using jCodec is unexceptable for me, and I can't see how I can use your code ether. But thank you anyway for the efforts. I'll kepp update this post as I'm progressing

Comment: I answered this part of your question 100% in my answer "I'm using VideoSurfaceView to render filtered video. I'm doing it by changing the fragment shader according to my needs" as said you can't make OpenGL process frames for you and make it return them to you, so you need to manually calculate everything you would do in a Fragment Shader, which was what I showed you how to do in my answer.

Comment: that's right, you did gave a solution for how to render the a frame without the use of fragment shader, but as I see it I need to add to this solution another part of the extraction and decoding of each frame, then put the result in the BufferedImage  and just then processing the filter. Now doing it for each frame sounds really wasteful. it will take a few minutes until will have all the filtered frames..Let's say that your solution reduce my problem to "how to get all the frames of a video in an acceptable time". Do you aggre with me?(If not it's fine :) maybe I don't see it right

Comment: "Now doing it for each frame sounds really wasteful" by saying that, I don't really think you understand how applying an effect works. You NEED to do it to all the frames. Also here on Stack Overflow we aren't required to give you every single thing in coding to make your program work, we are only here to advice you, so I already did enough, I didn't even have to write any code to answer your question.

Comment: yes you didn't even have to answered my question, but you did, and I think that your solution is not fully correct so it's right to discuss about it, I don't see any harm done, and if you feels that you gave enough on that thread that is Okey. Thank you anyway

Comment: I don't think you fully understand the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a very broad answer to the Question and overcomplicated with shift-operators shadowing the sense behind it.